# How to concatenate char* and LPWSTR string?

Tags: c++, windows, string-concatenation, lpwstr

I want to use MoveFile function, this function use two LPWSTR arguments, but I have one char* and LWSTR, how to concatenate them?

```
//move file
    LPWSTR latestFile = L"test.SPL";
    char*  spoolFolder = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\spool\PRINTERS\\";
    LPWSTR fileToMove = spoolFolder + latestFile;
    BOOL moved = MoveFile(latestFile, L"C:\\UnprocessedFiles\\" + latestFile);
```

Comment: Besides all the rest, here is a more fundamental problem: you cannot rely on the spool folder being always in that location - for starters, the Windows directory may be on another drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::wstring latestFile = wstring("test.SPL");
std::wstring spoolFolder = wstring("C:\\Windows\\System32\\spool\PRINTERS\\");
std::wstring fileToMove = spoolFolder + latestFile; 
BOOL moved = MoveFile(latestFile.c_str(), fileToMove.c_str());
```

In deed, LPWSTR is just a typdef for w_char*. so if you consult MSDN you will see that:

```
typded wchar_t* LPWSTR;
```

here the w_char* means that your string will be encoded as UNICODE not ANSI scheme. So under windows a UNICODE string will be an UTF16 one ( 2 bytes for each char).

std::wstring is also a typedef for std::basic_string`<wchar_t,char_traits<>>` so by declaring your inputs as wstring and calling wasting.c_str() this will do the stuff.

Comment: It would be good to explain why these lines of code resolve the OP question.

Comment: std::wstring("test.SPL") **does not** work. In fact, that constructor does not exist in the standard library. Maybe you wanted to use `std::wstring(std::begin(myStr), std::end(myStr));`, or, more simply, just put an `L` in front of the string literals. Also, you're not consistent in your use of the `std` prefix, and you forgot to escape a backslash in the second string. Maybe it would be useful to mention the use of raw strings to avoid that last problem.

Comment: Should UTF16 be UTF-16LE for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Just for clarification, LPWSTR is a typedef for `wchar_t*`. You can use [wcscat_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx) to conctenate strings of this form. Your one `char*` string should just be changed to be of the same type, since you have it there as a simple literal (just prefix the literal with `L` and change the declared type). Since you tagged this as C++, however, you can do all of this more simply by using the [std::wstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/wstring/) class.